# Find the color of a rectangle box in Python using graphics.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I am designing a game using graphics.py in python. I initially got everything setup except, the game consists of clicking on a box which would flip the color of the box. eg: if the color of the box clicked was white, it would turn black. My code works for turning the white boxes to black, but wont convert the black boxes to white. I know my if statement in while loop is wrong. I want to know how you could get the value of the color of the rectangle in graphics.py so I could make a proper if statement.

```
# _______________________IMPORTS_________________________
from graphics import *
import random
#________________________________________________________

win = None
m_board = []

# Description:
#  Wait for the user to enter a valid move via the mouse. If the player selects a position
#  outside the valid range or selects an occupied board space, the player is asked again.
#  The function returns the move only when it's valid.
# Return value:
#  An integer in the range 0 to 99 representing the move

def make_move():

    pos = win.getMouse()
    x_axis = pos.x // 50
    y_axis = pos.y // 50
    move = y_axis * 10 + x_axis


    return move


# Description:
#   Creating the initial board with random black and white boxes
# Return Value:
#   None

def draw_board():
    global win, m_board

    color = ["white", "black"]        #Creating list for the random black/white
    win = GraphWin("LOGICX", 500, 600)

    for y in range(0, 500, 50):
        for x in range(0, 500, 50):

            board_box = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x + 50, y + 50))                    
            #Setting the boxes with random black/white
            board_box.setFill(color[random.randint(0, 1)])            
            #Adding each box to the empty list
            m_board.append(board_box)            
            #Setting outline color to differentiate individual boxes
            board_box.setOutline("grey")
            board_box.draw(win)



    game_running = True
    while game_running:

        move = make_move()
        if m_board[move] == "black":
            m_board[move].setFill("white")

        else:
            m_board[move].setFill("black")
```

Comment: Use `cget()` if you want to find the color of a certain widget and then you can apply that in your code.

Comment: Is that a graphics.py method in python 3.x?

Comment: If it users tkinter then it should.

Comment: @Inkblot, yeah no! I am not using tkinter or turtle graphics!

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two significant problems with this code.  The first is this line:

```
if m_board[move] == "black":
```

You know that `m_board` is a list of `Rectangle` instances, why would you expect it to be equal to `"black"`?  We can get at the fill color this way:

```
if m_board[move].config["fill"] == "black":
```

Another approach would have been to wrap the `Rectangle` instances with your own object class that keeps track of things you need to query/change.  The second problem is this combination:

```
x_axis = pos.x // 50
y_axis = pos.y // 50
move = y_axis * 10 + x_axis
...
m_board[move].setFill("white")
```

Although double slash (//) does non-remainder division, since `pos.x` & `pos.y` are float, the result is a float and using a float list index, i.e `m_board[move]`, causes an error.  The simple fix is to have `make_move()` call `int()` on what it returns.

My rework of all the code:

```
import random
from graphics import *

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500, 500

COLUMNS, ROWS = 10, 10

TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT = WINDOW_WIDTH // COLUMNS, WINDOW_HEIGHT // ROWS

COLORS = ["white", "black"]  # Creating list for the random black/white

def make_move():

    pos = win.getMouse()

    x_axis = pos.x // TILE_WIDTH
    y_axis = pos.y // TILE_HEIGHT

    return int(y_axis * COLUMNS + x_axis)

def draw_board():
    board = []

    for y in range(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT):
        for x in range(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH):
            board_box = Rectangle(Point(x, y), Point(x + TILE_WIDTH, y + TILE_HEIGHT))
            # Set the boxes with random black/white
            board_box.setFill(random.choice(COLORS))
            # Set outline color to differentiate individual boxes
            board_box.setOutline("grey")
            # Add each box to the empty list
            board.append(board_box)
            board_box.draw(win)

    return board

win = GraphWin("LOGICX", WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

m_board = draw_board()

game_running = True

while game_running:

    move = make_move()

    if m_board[move].config["fill"] == "black":
        m_board[move].setFill("white")
    else:
        m_board[move].setFill("black")
```

Comment: It has been quite sometime since I have gotten back to this project. Thank you for the help.